# how to find all the values that exist in the sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

i want to check if value are exist in my sheet, and if it is, then to copy all the result to a1, a2 and so on...

i can't stop the looping of searching, if there is only 10 results i want it will stop after 10 cells.

```
Sub ex82()
Dim r As Range, b, d As Integer
d = 1
b = 0
Do While b = 0
    Set r = Cells.Find("54256")
    If Not r Is Nothing Then Range("A" & d).Value = 54256
    d = d + 1
    'if .... b =
Loop
End Sub
```

i need some if...

Comment: Once you write 54256 to a cell in column A your `Find` will find 54256 there... maybe you want to rethink this? Instead of a loop you could use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`.

Comment: `Dim r As Range, b, d As Integer` declares `b` to be a `Variant` rather than `Integer.` Also, you should consider using `Long` rather than `Integer`. You are risking overflow for no real gain.